# Couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap' in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline, sass

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap translated to SCSS files. It works in local-development, but when I precompile and push to Heroku (using Cedar stack), I get this:

```
> Started GET "/" for 74.57.16.130 at 2012-01-28 17:16:36 +0000 
> Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML  Rendered
> static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms) 
> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
> 
>  ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'  
> (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss.css:11)):
>      8: </head>
>      6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
>      4:   <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
>      2: <html>
>      5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>        
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in
> `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___288948710373692320_32137840'
>      3: <head>    cache: [GET /] miss
> 
>      7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>  cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.0, the app was working on Heroku until I added the SASS files.

Comment: Can you show me your application.css in you app/assets/js folder

Comment: all it has in the file is 
 *= require twitter/bootstrap

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are you using a gem? Make sure your gem is not part of the assets group and is accessible in production.

#### From GemFile

```
# Gems used only for assets and not in production environments by default.
```

So just move the gem outside of any group and you should be okay.

Comment: From what I had understood, I thought when I ran the precompile command, that it would compile all of the SASS files into one CSS file. Is this not the case? (I'm so new at this, but loving it)

Comment: I don't think the SASS from the gem you are using gets precompiled, I'm not sure anyway.

Comment: I think you've found the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mike you're god! If only i could upvote this 1000 times. _/\_

Answer (score 4):

Just put this in your gemfile

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", "~> 2.0rc0"
```

[There's invalid CSS in BootStrap 2.0](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1395) which causes SCSS compilation to fail

You can verify this by looking at the output of

```
git push heroku master
```

You should see some error like:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Invalid CSS after "...er-radius:0 \0/": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";}"
       (in /tmp/build_1k8ugei34dpcw/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)

       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
       Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
```

Answer (score 3):

In `config/environments/production.rb` add this line:

`config.assets.precompile = [/^[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\..*/]`

My guess is it is not adding all your assets.

Comment: I'mma try this when I get home. Thank you.

Is this considered regular(best) practice?

Comment: @JohnCho I have no idea. I just know that when I added more javascript files, my compiler in production was completely ignoring them, and I had to add this line.

Comment: I tried it this morning, modified the files, ran precompile, then push to heroku which all went fine, but I still have the same errors in the log. =(

Comment: @JohnCho what is `twitter/bootstrap` ? is that a file? Is it a folder?

Comment: It's a SCSS file that imports all of the other SCSS files in order (and it works as it should in development). I'm gonna try import via wildcard tonight, and see if it works in Production, then I'll know if it has to do with how things are imported. I'm grasping at straws a bit here.

Comment: This only works if you have a javascript compiler in production. "rake assets:precompile" and then pushing that is the preferred way.

Comment: i solved it by replacing the following line `config.assets.compile = false` with `config.assets.compile = true`

Answer (score 2):

this solved the issue in heroku at least

just downgrade to sass-rails 3.1.4

```
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.1.4'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.2'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see something like this when you are deploying rails app to heroku.com

```
Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
...
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port xxxx?
```

Just add this to config/application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, in config/environments/production.rb, you have...

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```