# rake aborted! couldn't find file twitter/bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

i'm following the Hartl tutorial about ROR 3.2, i build a simple app that works fine locally but when i try to deploy it to heroku wit $git push heroku master , the rake assets:precompile fails because  "couldn't find file twitter/bootstrap". (error raised by application.js) 
I've already google the problem but none of these answers work for me:
[Heroku deploy fails after upgrading to bootstrap 2.0.1 via twitter-bootstrap-rails gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423067/heroku-deploy-fails-after-upgrading-to-bootstrap-2-0-1-via-twitter-bootstrap-rai)

[Couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap' in Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047478/rails-app-with-twitter-bootstrap-works-in-development-but-not-in-production)

can anyone help me to figure out the problem? 
If i have to attach some files, or if you needother informations please tell me.
Thank you

here the Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

group :development do
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '~> 2.0.1.0'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.3'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that got fixed by moving bootstrap related gems out of the assets group in gemfile. Paste it alongside the regular list of gems and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added:

```
# Allow compilation of assests on Heroku
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

to your config/application.rb file? This was the last step I did to fix my Heroku woes.

Also you should be fine leaving gem `'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.3'` in your `group assets do` block despite what I've read online.

Sounds like a problem in your gem file, here's an example one that's working fine on Heroku:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.3'
end

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'pg', '0.13.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'simple_form', '2.0.1'
```

Comment: It don't work unfortunately, i'v tried it directly on heroku (because locally now i have another issue running bundle install due to therubyracer) and now rake was aborted because "application.css has already been required".
My application.css has only
' *= require_self
 *= require_tree . '

Comment: ok now i don't have anymore the issue about therubyracer but the problem it's still the same, anyone?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by using following steps:

1. Move **twitter-bootstrap-rails** gem from outside of :assets in gemfile
2. Update **twitter-bootstrap-rails** gem version **2.2.6** or 
   just paste below line in your gemfile.
   **gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'**

if twitter-bootstrap-rails 2.2.6 is not working then Use twitter-bootstrap-rails gem latest version.