# Git Push Heroku Master - Failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

so i tried pushing this app to heroku:

```
https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr
```

i am using virtualbox with ubuntu.

i installed ruby using this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl   # Required
$ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable   # Get RVM
$ source ~/.bashrc   # Reboot the shell
$ rvm requirements   # To get the command below
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-   core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion  # Install Libraries
$ rvm install 1.9.3   # Install ruby v1.9.3
$ rvm use 1.9.3
$ gem install rails   # Install rails (I had to run this command twice. Error trying to find railties the first time.. weird)
```

However when i create my heroku app and tries to push the app to it it gives me this error:

```
http://pastebin.com/uF5PUsCM
```

for database i installed postgresql (dont know if it has any relevance though)

Comment: What is the result of 'git remote'?  When you create an app with the Heroku CLI client it adds a 'remote' to which you will push.  This comes from your local machine NOT from GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that git push heroku does indeed push to heroku (git remote -v would confirm it), the error messages are:

```
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb.
   rake aborted!
   refer/cream-tooltip@2x.png isn't precompiled
```

You can find a few suggestion in "[Ruby on Rails Rake assets:precompile error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7464544/6309)" and in [this issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/474#issuecomment-14736295):

> Open up `config/environments/production.rb` and make sure the following option is set to true:

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

> Then run:

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

[Check also your gems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9137045/6309).

Comment: hey, thanks for the help. I did everything you said, however when i run the last command (rake assets:...):i get the following error:    /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'